# Pluggable database does not exist

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have Been Working with `Oracle sql developer` almost for a year now, I have many users created including HR.
Earlier today I've connected to my pluggable database and things went fine.
Now when I write in the `CMD`:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = PDBORCL;
```

It says: `ORA-65011: Pluggable database PDBORCL does not exist.`
But it absolutely exists! Because I've been working with it so many times.
Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few possibilities:

1. you or someone unplugged pdborcl
2. you or someone renamed pdborcl
3. you are not connected to the database you think you are

This will show the PDBs you have:

```
SELECT pdb_name, status
  FROM cdb_pdbs
```

And since you're in SQL Developer, you can use the CDB interface on the DBA panel to see what you have and make changes.

[image]

And finally, I would generally recommend users to connect directly to their PDB in SQL Developer. Have a connection defined for the PDB Listener Service, and connect to that, vs connecting to a Container and switching over in a worksheet via the ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER command like you are doing.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I Tried the `Select Query` you provided in my CMD, and I Found my Pluggable database under the name `PDBORCL` which is the correct name I'm using and the Status is `Normal` But the error is still the same and I Can't Connect to it.

Comment: I have also tried to `SHUTDOWN` but the following error appeared:
`ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kpdb-no-proc-uid], [3], [1], [0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []`.
I'm trying all these command from my windows 10 cmd like I have always did after writing the two commands:
`lsnrctl reload` and `sqlplus / as sysdba`.

Comment: ORA-600 = not good. Try a shutdown abort...and I hope you have a backup. Also, any messages in your alert log? Maybe you filled up a disk/tablespaces?

Comment: `SHUTDOWN ABORT` worked for me.
I Don't have a backup but it's okay I just want to be able to connect to my pluggable database.
then `Startup` worked for me and now it's fixed!!
Thank you so much Sir.

Answer (score 1):

I've the problem and solved as per above @miriam-arbaji solution:

Run cmd -> `lsnrctl reload` and `sqlplus / as sysdba`

Then run any SQL cmds.